# URL Rewrite in Azure Front Door (Preview) Standard/Premium

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

We have 2 app services: `foo.azurewebsites.net` and `bar.azurewebsites.net` and have configured origin groups for both sites. We would like the front door to do path based routing: i.e.:

```
myfd.z01.azurefd.net/foo -> foo.azurewebsites.net
myfd.z01.azurefd.net/bar -> bar.azurewebsites.net
```

We can configure this to work using `Patterns to match` on the routes as `/foo/*` and `/bar/*` respectively. This works as expected.

Next, we want to rewrite the URL so that we don't get the initial `/foo` or `/bar` path sent to the web apps. In other words, the current setup produces the following:

```
myfd.z01.azurefd.net/foo/abc -> foo.azurewebsites.net/foo/abc
myfd.z01.azurefd.net/bar/def -> bar.azurewebsites.net/bar/def
```

What we *want* is:

```
myfd.z01.azurefd.net/foo/abc -> foo.azurewebsites.net/abc
myfd.z01.azurefd.net/bar/def -> bar.azurewebsites.net/def
```

So we set up a rewrite URL rule as follows:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Action | URL rewrite |
| Source pattern | `/foo/` |
| Destination | `/` |
| Preserve unmatched path | `Yes` |

However, this does not appear to work. In the `AzureDiagnostics` logs we can see the rule is firing, but the URL is not being rewritten - it still contains `/foo/`. Is there something we are missing?

Comment: did my answer help you in this case? If not, it would be interesting for me what is not working, so I may can update my answer.

Comment: Please accept Pirmin Rehm answer. It is great and explain everything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Problem analysis

I came across the same issue and after some experiments I derive the following behavior for the current state of the Azure Front Door (Preview) Standard/Premium:

**If in the Endpoint Manager a Route is configured to match a sub path, e.g. `/foo/*`, to route to a specific Origin, an enabled UrlRewrite Rule is only applied for the path which is following `/foo`. e.g.**

```
Route:
  Pattern to match: /foo/*
  OriginGroup: Foo
Rule: UrlRewrite
  Source pattern "/"
  Destination "/bar/"
  Preserve unmatched path: true
```

will result in a rewrite from e.g. `/foo/baz` to `/foo/bar/baz` and thus will not work for the given issue. However, there are two options to accomplish the desired result.

## Solutions

### Way 1: Use the *Origin path* in the Route config instead of a Rule

The *Origin path* overwrites the *Pattern to match* and is thus itself already an UrlRewrite. Nevertheless, via the Azure Portal UI it is not allowed to set only `/` as path, but via the [`az afd route update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cli/azure/afd/route?view=azure-cli-latest#az_afd_route_update) CLI it is possible and works:

> **Update 2022** - you can now also set '/' as origin path via Azure Portal

[image: screenshot of azure portal route config]

No extra Rules are required here.

### Way 2: Don't use different Routes but Rules with *Origin group overwrite*

Only one Route is configured matching all requests `/*` and serving a default Origin. To this route a Rule set is applied which contains for each origin an *Origin group overwerite* and a * Url rewrite* rule:
[image]

Comment: Man you are my day saver. Great solution. I did try use routes but now I see i do not need them at all. Just use origin path. Thanks

Comment: I was struggling with terraform and cdn_frontdoor_origin_path = "/" did the trick. You saved my day. ☕

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to use rewrite for this, just use simple forwarding with a route  rule to match your pattern and forward to respective back end pools