# Azure Front Door URL rewrite to display pages from microsite hosted in different domain

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-front-door

We have a website (`https://www.example.com`), which is load-balanced using Azure Front Door.

We have a microsite (`https://www.microsite.example/`), which hosts some informational pages.

We now have a requirement to load the `wellbeing` site pages through the main site URL.
For example: if the user types in the URL `https://www.example.com/wellbeing`, the browser URL must remain the same. However, we need to display the `wellbeing` site pages.

I added a rewrite rule in the ruleset configuration to implement the above requirement.

```
Rule details: 
Action: Url rewrite
Source Pattern: /wellbeing
Destination:/www.microsite.example
Preserve unmatched path: Yes.
```

The rewrite fails, and when I look at the logs, I can see the
origin value requested as:
`https://www.example.com:443/www.microsite.example/`.

**Screen shot of the ruleset:**
[image]

Is this requirement possible. How can I rewrite the URL to a different domain without changing the browser URL?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the below stack over flow question. The answer provided by @`[Pirmin Rehm][1]` worked for me. I have upvoted his answer in the original question.

[URL Rewrite in Azure Front Door (Preview) Standard/Premium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564910/url-rewrite-in-azure-front-door-preview-standard-premium?rq=2)

I have also pasted the rule I setup in my instance:
[image: origin group approach]